# Is there a way to get threads to not compete as hard for I/O resources?

Tags: rust, concurrency, parallel-processing

I wrote the following parallel test case, which runs at least 2x slower than the `md5sum` binary:

```
// dependencies are md-5 = "0.9.1", rayon = "1.5.0", hex-slice = "0.1.4"

use std::{
    convert::TryInto,
    env::args_os,
    fs::File,
    io::{Error, Read},
    path::PathBuf,
};

use hex_slice::AsHex;
use md5::{self, digest::Digest};
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    args_os()
        .skip(1)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .par_iter()
        .for_each(|path| {
            println!(
                "{:02x}  {}",
                md5sum(PathBuf::from(&path)).unwrap().plain_hex(false),
                path.to_string_lossy()
            );
        });
}

fn md5sum(path: PathBuf) -> Result<[u8; 16], Error> {
    let mut file = File::open(path)?;
    let mut ctx = md5::Md5::default();
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; 2_097_152];
    loop {
        let bytes_read = file.read(&mut buf)?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            break;
        }
        ctx.update(&buf[0..bytes_read]);
    }
    Ok(ctx.finalize().try_into().unwrap())
}
```

If I remove the parallelism (change `par_iter()` to `iter()`), it becomes a bit faster than the `md5sum` binary, so the compiler and the md-5 crate are certainly not the problem. The algorithm is not totally I/O bound because two `md5sum` processes are a little faster than one process operating on two files.

Test background: I'm flushing disk cache in between tests by using SysInternals RamMap to empty the working sets and the standby list. Other background: I'm running the code in WSL2 but checksumming files in a Windows folder. The data is on a traditional hard drive.

I tried ThreadPool, async reads with tokio (parallel+concurrent with a semaphore to make sure not too many files were opened), and Rayon (as above). I tried buffer sizes from 512 KB to 10 MB. The OS or drive controller should be smart enough to read the data as fast as possible, but it's not working out, perhaps because the system wants to put a lower bound on latency. Is there any way to get decent performance with concurrent reads?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution: I got some speedup by limiting I/O with a [Semaphore](https://docs.rs/std-semaphore/0.1.0/std_semaphore/struct.Semaphore.html) (not a mutex because on SSD I will want to allow more than one read). I rearranged the code to do the read separately from the computation, but that isn't suitable for very large files.

The reads will be sequential, but the computation can happen in parallel:

```
fn md5sum(io_lock: Arc<Semaphore>, path: PathBuf) -> Result<[u8; 16], Error> {
    let buf = {
        let _lock = io_lock.access();
        let mut file = File::open(path)?;
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        file.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
        buf
    };
    Ok(md5::Md5::digest(&buf).try_into().unwrap())
}
```

It would still be nice to know if there's a way to let the OS optimize reads.